# submit button working slow contact form 7 wordpress

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I am using a contact form 7 but when submit form button work slowly so user click multiple time and form submit 2-3 time need help

Here are the URL [Link](https://www.fnpgardens.com/wedding-venues-gurgaon/the-ritz/?promo=gurgaonnav_dt_tab)

Comment: i tried now, its work fine click one time wait 5 second for check form by google and work.

Comment: Same here as @SimoneRossaini did work fine for me, So I guess it is their connection that are slow. 
But one thing I saw that you get an 500 error on a post to some url

Comment: that is the main problem it take time for rshowing thankyou message

Comment: You can disable button after clicked once. So, no one can click multiple time

Comment: Check your connection OR clear browser cache !

Comment: disable button after clicked once @WP Developer please guide

Comment: I have added answer of script. You can check it

Answer (score 1):

You can get click event of submit button from [here](https://contactform7.com/dom-events/).

Try this code if it works.

```
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7submit', function( event ) {
    alert( "Fire!" );
    jQuery('your-button-id-or-class').prop("disabled", true);
}, false );
```

Or you can find solution [here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/disable-submit-after-click-in-contact-form-7/).

Hope this helps you.